# Mat input field placeholder overlap issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat input field with a placeholder.I am binding data to that input field with an array coming from a service response.The data is showing correctly on the input field but it is overlapping with my placeholder.

I checked the solution for this issue but couldn't find one.

I am using @angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12 and Angular 4.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no_pad mb20 nopadMbl">
    <form class="col-xs-12 no_pad example-form">
        <mat-form-field class="col-xs-12 nopadMbl example-full-width" *ngFor = "let data of b">
            <input matInput placeholder="Tower" name ="Tower" class="col-xs-12 no_pad" [(ngModel)] ="data.Tower">
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: check your styles, it really might be some positioning, etc, material design creates those placeholders as elements

Comment: I read one solution in GitHub where it was mentioned that If I could re-compile my material theming.scss file ,that would fix the issue.  But I don't know how to do that.I tried to fix it through Css but it didn't work

Comment: I am not clicking on that mat input filed.I am populating data in that field using two way data binding ,so in that case how to handle the placeholder text ?If i had to click and type some input in that field I could have wrote a click event where after clicking on the input field the placeholder would move up.

Comment: I too used two way data binding on such inputs and placeholders moved up themselves if there was a non empty value prepopulated in the input, layout was kind of `<mat-form-field><input name="email" [(ngModel)]="pupil.email" email matInput placeholder="Email">
        </mat-form-field>`, which looks quite like yours what leads me to think that problem is in styling

Comment: By styling you mean to say CSS file for that particular component need a fix or material styling?

Comment: It's working now.The issue was that the prebuilt themes of angular material was not imported in the main style.css file.Thanks for the guidance

Comment: @nikhil : Could you elaborate on the fix you found?